# Function Not Updating To Live Values : Avalonia UI

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm trying to update a "TotalGearboxRatio" based on the latest gearbox definition. It works as expected except that it is updated based on values that are previously set (compared to the values live in the UI). How do I make sure it updates from the live values?

I am using an ObservableCollection for the ItemsControl that has a item property update event like BindingList does. In that update event I have a check to update UI based on the items, and then I update the total gearbox ratio afterwards in the same event call. Below is the code:

Xaml Control

```
<TextBlock Text="Gearbox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

<ItemsControl Width="200" ItemsSource="{ Binding Gearbox }">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, 16, *">
        <NumericUpDown Value="{ Binding Driving, Mode=TwoWay }" Minimum="1" FormatString="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="0" />

        <TextBlock Text=":" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

        <NumericUpDown Value="{ Binding Driven, Mode=TwoWay }" Minimum="1" FormatString="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="2" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

<Grid Width="180" ColumnDefinitions="*, 16, *">
    <TextBlock Text="Total Ratio" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Text="->" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBlock Text="{ Binding TotalGearRatio }" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

View Model

```
using PhysicsSim.Models;
using ReactiveUI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Utilities;

namespace PhysicsSim.ViewModels;

public class ControlViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _CalculatorIndex = 0;

    private List<string> _MotorSelection;

    private int _MotorIndex = 0;

    // Motor Values

    // Motor Count

    // Voltage

    private FullyObservableCollection<GearboxStage> _Gearbox = new()
    {
        new GearboxStage { Driving = 1, Driven = 1 },
        new GearboxStage { Driving = 1, Driven = 1 },
    };

    private string _TotalGearRatio = "1   :   1";

    public ControlViewModel()
    {
        Motors _Motors = new();

        _MotorSelection = _Motors.GetMotorNames();

        Gearbox = _Gearbox;

        Gearbox.ItemPropertyChanged += Gearbox_ItemPropertyChanged;
    }

    public int CalculatorIndex
    {
        get => _CalculatorIndex;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _CalculatorIndex, value);
    }

    public List<string> MotorSelection
    {
        get => _MotorSelection;
        set => _MotorSelection = value;
    }

    public int MotorIndex
    {
        get => _MotorIndex;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _MotorIndex, value);
    }

    public FullyObservableCollection<GearboxStage> Gearbox
    {
        get => _Gearbox;
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Gearbox, value); }
    }

    private void Gearbox_ItemPropertyChanged(object? sender, ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckGearbox();

        var gearbox = Gearbox.ToList();

        UpdateGearboxRatio(gearbox);
    }

    void CheckGearbox()
    {
        var last = Gearbox.Last();
        var slast = Gearbox.ElementAt(Gearbox.Count - 2);

        if (last.Driving != 1 || last.Driven != 1)
        {
            Gearbox.Add(new GearboxStage { Driving = 1, Driven = 1 });
        }
        else if ((last.Driving == 1 && last.Driven == 1) && (slast.Driving == 1 && slast.Driven == 1))
        {
            if (Gearbox.Count == 2)
            {
                return;
            }

            Gearbox.Remove(last);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateGearboxRatio(List<GearboxStage> gearbox)
    {
        double ratio = 1;

        foreach (GearboxStage stage in gearbox)
        {
            ratio *= stage.Ratio;
        }

        if (ratio > 0)
        {
            TotalGearRatio = String.Format("{0:0.##}   :   1", ratio);
        }
        else if (ratio < 0)
        {
            TotalGearRatio = String.Format("1   :   {0:0.##}", ratio);
        }
    }

    public string TotalGearRatio
    {
        get => _TotalGearRatio;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _TotalGearRatio, value);
    }
}
```

Gearbox Class

```
using ReactiveUI;

namespace PhysicsSim.Models;

public class GearboxStage : ReactiveObject
{
    private int _Driving;

    private int _Driven;

    public double Ratio;

    public int Driving
    {
        get => _Driving;
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Driving, value); Ratio = (double)Driven / (double)Driving; }
    }

    public int Driven
    {
        get => _Driven;
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Driven, value); Ratio = (double)Driven / (double)Driving; }
    }
}
```

Sorry if this is a silly question. Thanks in advance though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UpdateGearboxRatio()` should have been at the end of the `CheckGearbox()` function so that it is using the latest `Gearbox`. I also removed the `Ratio` value from the `GearboxStage` class to make sure that it was calculating with the latest data within the view model.